# Decimal representation of a whole number is of lower size than the whole number itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, memory

In python, Why does the decimal representation of same number shows to occupy lesser space in memory(almost half)?

```
sys.getsizeof(1234561111111111111111111111111111111111111112223567744.0)
24
sys.getsizeof(1234561111111111111111111111111111111111111112223567744)
48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to Python 2.7, you would get the same with Python 3.

Your two numbers are not the same: the first one is a float, that will be stored as a float (and so rounded), and will use the same number of bytes whatever its value (in the allowed range for floats):

```
a = 1234561111111111111111111111111111111111111112223567744.0
>>> a
1.2345611111111112e+54
```

while the second one is an integer, which will be stored with unlimited precision (all digits are kept):

```
b = 1234561111111111111111111111111111111111111112223567744
>>> b
1234561111111111111111111111111111111111111112223567744
```

The size needed to store it will grow without limit with the number of digits.

Comment: When you say first one will be stored as float and rounded, is there a size/length limit to this as for smaller float/decimal numbers, I don't think there is any rounding off happening.

Comment: I have updated the question.Is there a way to get this back to float because below produces a different number entirely. `a=1234561111111111111111111111111111111111111112223567744.01
 print( "%.2f" % float(str(a))) 1234561111109999993203066987989422162054126101852061696.00`

Comment: Floats have limited precision (have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken for more details), so there is no way you can have a float represented exactly with that many digits. What is stored is the nearest representable value, not the one you entered. You could have a look at the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html) module if you want an exact representation of decimal numbers.